# How to draw a polygon with clear spaces inside in EAGLE

Tags: eaglecad

As title EAGLE don't allow me to draw a clear space inside a polygon. I've a GND polygon plane and I don't want that a zone inside it is filled with this plane.

How I can do that?

Comment: teke a look [here](http://www.element14.com/community/thread/13637/l/making-cut-out-in-filled-polygon)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Draw a 'Cut-out' polygon. Basically this says everything between the cutout polygon and a polygon outside of it should be filled. Everything inside the cutout will not be filled.

When drawing the polygon there  is a symbol on the top bar which looks like a filled box with an empty polygon space inside. Alternatively if you go into the properties you can change the type.

---

An example of a cutout polygon:
[image: Cutout Polygon]

Answer (score 3):

Draw another polygon on the tRestrict or bRestrict layers in the space you don't want a copper fill.

The restrict layers keep copper (fill or traces) from being placed and the keepout layers will throw errors if you place components there.

From the help:

```
39 tKeepout   Nogo areas for components, top side
40 bKeepout   Nogo areas for components, bottom side
41 tRestrict  Nogo areas for tracks, top side
42 bRestrict  Nogo areas for tracks, bottom side
```